# 0 Width column still showing up in Copied Data

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a custom column at the start of my gantt view, this column somehow got shrunk to 0px.  When I copy data to excel, the data still shows up.  I cannot figure out how to make that column have a width.  If I try to add the column again, when I copy to excel it is there twice.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Task-> View (Drop Down)-> Reset to default

This should bring all your columns back to a finite widt